# Mysql Insert if not exist in two column

Tags: mysql, sql, insert-into

I looked into MySQL duplicate key but cant figure it out.

I have a table like below:

```
id   series   chapter   path(can be unique)
```

I want only insert data and not update. Lets say I have data like below:

seri:Naruto, klasor:567 ==> If both of these exist in table then do not insert.

seri:Naruto, klasor:568 ==> If Naruto exist but 568 does not exist then do insert.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 4):

Easiest way would be to define unique index with two columns on that table:

```
ALTER TABLE yourtable ADD UNIQUE INDEX (seri,klasor);
```

You may also define two column primary key, which would work just as well.

Then use `INSERT IGNORE` to only add rows when they will not be duplicates:

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO yourtable (seri, klasor) VALUES ('Naruto',567);
INSERT IGNORE INTO yourtable (seri, klasor) VALUES ('Naruto',568);
```

**Edit:** As per comments, you can't use `UNIQUE INDEX` which complicates things.

```
SET @seri='Naruto';
SET @klasor=567;
INSERT INTO yourtable 
 SELECT seri,klasor FROM (SELECT @seri AS seri, @klasor AS klasor)
  WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT seri, klasor FROM yourtable WHERE seri=@seri AND klasor=@klasor);
```

You may use the above query with two local variables or convert it to single statement by replacing the local variables with actual values.

Better way would be to use [stored procedure](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-procedure.html):

```
CREATE PROCEDURE yourinsert (vseri VARCHAR(8), vklasor INT)
BEGIN
 DECLARE i INT;
 SELECT COUNT(*) INTO i FROM yourtable WHERE seri=vseri AND klasor=vklasor;

 IF i=0 THEN
  INSERT INTO yourtable (seri,klasor) VALUES (vseri, vklasor);
 END IF;
END;
```

This would allow you to perform the `INSERT` using:

```
CALL yourinsert('Naruto',567);
```

Comment: I think i cant define unique index. A lot same data in that two colum.

Comment: So you need to keep the existing duplicates, but don't want to introduce more?

Comment: Yes. I am inserting like for example  Current Data in Mysql :`1+2+3`,  What I get from PHP: `1+2+3+4+5`. So only Insert: `+4+5`. I dont know maybe Update 123 with same data and insert 45 works?

Comment: I tried it but its giving syntax error. I using PDO binding parameters like `:seri` and `seri=:seri`.

Comment: I am trying first one but gettin error `Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens`. I simply change your code to `@seri=:gnc1, @klasor:gnc2`

Comment: Sorry i forgot the mention I need insert data to 1 more column. `path` column need be inserted along with it.

Answer (score 3):

```
INSERT INTO table_name (seri, klasor) VALUES ('Naruto',567)
WHERE NOT EXISTS( SELECT seri,klasor FROM table_name WEHERE seri='Naruto' AND klasor=567
)
```

Hope this helps..

Comment: im getting `SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE NOT EXISTS`

Comment: found solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45252377/syntax-error-near-where-not-exist