# Syntax Error near WHERE NOT EXIST

Tags: mysql, sql, syntax

i search in stack but None of them had reached the final answer.
My query is this :

```
    INSERT INTO user (username,frequence,autoSend) 
    VALUES('feri2','3','1') 
    WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT * FROM user WHERE username='feri2')
```

When run,I receive the syntax parsing error:

```
SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT * FROM user WHERE username='feri2')' at line 1
```

I don't know how I can fix it, where is the problem?

Comment: You cannot use WHERE with INSERT unless you also have a SELECT

Comment: @GarrGodfrey i did it on another table and it works for me !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to change the syntax slightly, try the following:

```
INSERT INTO user (username,frequence,autoSend)
SELECT * FROM (SELECT 'feri2','3','1') AS `values`
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT username FROM user WHERE username='feri2'
) LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: If you are trying to do this with prepared statements where your columns might have the same value, give your column names aliases in the subquery: `SELECT * FROM (SELECT ? as col1, ? as col2, ? as col3) AS \`values\``

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want duplicate users, you should probably have a UNIQUE index on the `username` column.  If you add that, then you can simply:

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO user (username,frequence,autoSend) 
VALUES('feri2','3','1')
```

If there is already a user 'feri2', then it will do nothing.

Comment: thank you for answer.that work but i don't want use from INSERT IGNORE